# Get tags from URL segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an web app using Codeigniter.
In this app I got a tag based search. I need people to be able to use an URL where
the tags are predefined and then do a search using them.

Like this:

```
http://example.com/search/tags/tag1/tag2/tag3
```

How can I get all segments (tags) efter the tags segment?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you want to use in controller

```
$tags = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with function explode():

```
$url = "http://example.com/search/tags/tag1/tag2/tag3";

list($url_part, $segments) = explode("/tags/", $url);

$tags_array = explode("/", $segments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var url = http://example.com/search/tags/tag1/tag2/tag3;

parts = url.split('/');
alert(parts[1]);
   ​});
</script>
```

You have to fetch array values according to u.